# Flutter How to give a Container border bottom only

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In Flutter how to set a border for the bottom only,

As shown in the picture below, I have a Container with Text, showing a red color border from the bottom, Kindly guide how to set a border from the bottom only.

[image]

Comment: Give Border a bottom argument. Border(bottom: ...)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `Border` with the `bottom` argument.

```
Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.5, color: Colors.grey[300]),
            ),
          ),
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(title),
            subtitle: Text(score + dateFormatted),
            trailing: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                 children: [
                    Text(amount),
                    Checkbox(
                       value: false,
                       activeColor: Colors.green,
                       onChanged: (bool newValue) {}),
                    ],
                   ),
           ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

better to use `ListView.separator` constructor

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: Home()));

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(body: Demo());
}

class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: 42,
      separatorBuilder: (_, __) => Container(height: 1.5, color: Colors.grey[300]),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text('item $index'),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]