# Flutter: How can I customize the Border of a Container (or other Widgets)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a special requirement on my `Container` border.
It should only have a border on the *left*, *right* and *bottom* but **not** on the top.

```dart
Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(146, 94, 58, 1.0),
              border: Border.all(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(85, 63, 48, 1.0),
                width: 2,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(2),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(2),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

I can only find `.all` and `.symmetric` but nothing like `.only` which I have seen for the `BorderRadius` Widget. Why is it missing for `Border` and how can I make this still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[look this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594033/flutter-how-to-give-a-container-border-bottom-only)

[and you can read this article](https://googleflutter.com/flutter-container-border-left-right-top-bottom/)

```
Container(
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.5, color: Colors.grey[300]),
            ),
          ),
)
```